# Range numbers in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, numbers, arguments

I wrote a function that creates an array from a given range of numbers, but it doesn't work.

```js
function makeListFromRange(start, end) {
  return Array(end - start + 1).fill().map((_, idx) => start + idx)
}

const result = makeListFromRange([2, 7]); // should be [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You are passing an array when calling the function, while the function expects two arguments. Use `makeListFromRange(2, 7)` instead.

Comment: I need to pass an array with numbers

Comment: `makeListFromRange(...[2, 7])` would work.

Comment: So destructure it in the function - `makeListFromRange([start, end])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input needs to be an array, use array destructuring to get `start` and `end`:

```js
function makeListFromRange([start, end]) {
  return Array(end - start + 1).fill().map((_, idx) => start + idx)
}

const result = makeListFromRange([2, 7]); // should be [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

console.log(result);
```

A simpler solution would be to supply `start` and `end` as arguments:

```js
function makeListFromRange(start, end) {
  return Array(end - start + 1).fill().map((_, idx) => start + idx)
}

const result = makeListFromRange(2, 7); // should be [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I'm so inconsiderate, thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Stupid mistake that happened to all of us at least once :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function expects two parameters, each of which should be a single number. To pass in an array of length two, you need to use the spread operator (`...`).

```js
function makeListFromRange(start, end) {
  return Array(end - start + 1).fill().map((_, idx) => start + idx)
}

const result = makeListFromRange(...[2, 7]); // should be [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

console.log(result);
```